# Cortana voice command sample can not execute voice commands supported

Tags: c#, cortana

I have download Cortana voice command sample and running it in my windows10 system. I do not know if VCD file installed incorrect and How to determine it.the function "OnActivation()" never excute when I speak to cortana.